# How do i create drawer icon animation like in material design where the three lines turn into an arrow on drawer open?

Tags: android

How do i create drawer icon animation like in material design where the three lines turn into an arrow on drawer open ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use vector-compat, that uses SVG image to make the desired behavior.

https://github.com/wnafee/vector-compat

```
android {
    // use version 22 or higher
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
    ...
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.wnafee:vector-compat:1.0.5'
    ...
}
```

Example (1st image):

[image]

```
<com.wnafee.vector.MorphButton
    android:id="@+id/drawerBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    app:vc_backgroundTint="#f50057"
    app:vc_foregroundTint="#3F51B5"
    app:vc_startDrawable="@drawable/ic_arrow_to_drawer"
    app:vc_endDrawable="@drawable/ic_drawer_to_arrow"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use for example `TransitionDrawable`, these posts should give you information how to use it:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/TransitionDrawable.html

http://kirill-poletaev.blogspot.fi/2013/02/android-beginner-tutorial-part-88.html